# How to append in a file in Java using OutputStream for different Protocol(FTP,HTTP,SFTP)

Tags: java, java-io, outputstream, fileoutputstream, dataoutputstream

I want to write data to a file(If present then append else create new) present on my ftp server(locally running). I am having a List<byte[]> of a file.

```
public void write(List<byte[]> bytes, String path)throws Exception{
   URL url = new URL(path);
   URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
   DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
   for (byte[] byte : bytes) {
      out.write(byte);
   }
   out.close();
}
```

**NOTE: Path could be an HTTP or FTP or SFTP url.**

It is overwriting on file. I want to append in file which is already present at that location.
How to enable append mode in  OutputStream?

Comment: I am not sure this is achieveable through `DataOutputStream` since there is a special FTP verb for appending content. Is there a specific reason you do not use a dedicated FTP client for this?

Comment: This isn't right, use an FTP client library to read, write, etc. files on an FTP server. Blindly writing on a `DataOutputStream` is never going to work, you're overlooking the FTP protocol that's required for sending a file.

Comment: I have to write data to multiple endpoint like HTTP, FTP, SFTP. What should I use so that it work for any endpoint?